# How to validate date within current year using jQuery Validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery Validate plugin and wanted to know how can I validate that a given date is in the current year?

I have this code that make sure the field is required and that it is a valid date, but I want to also make sure the date is in the current year, current being 2017

```
// orders dates fields are required and must be in current year

$(".order-dates").each(function (item) {
    $(this).rules("add", {
        required: true,
        date: true
    });
});
```

Comment: you don't need the `.each()` at all I think. `.rules` *should* operate over a collection - since it's a plugin. It's absolutely strange `item` is left secret from us... *`"I want to also make sure the date is in the current year, current being 2017"`* ... what *date*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090401/jquery-validate-year-not-greater-than-today

Comment: I'm using a class for the field names, so the each() loop is to iterate over all fields with that class.   The fields I'm iterating over have date values in them.  They could be any date value as they are used entered.  "Item" is the date value and $(this) represents the field element!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, the `.each()` is absolutely required here since this plugin's methods can only be attached to a single element, not a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create a custom method to `jquery-validator` and use this in your validation rules

This is what your custom method will be (I am assuming you've added a class `class="date"` in your field)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.validator.addMethod("ifDateInCurrentYear", function(value, element) {
        var date= $('.date').val();
   if(Date.parse(date).getFullYear() - new Date().getFullYear() == 0)
      return true;
   else return false;
    }, "* Date is not valid");

});
</script>
```

You can use this like

```
$(".order-dates").each(function (item) {
$(this).rules("add", {
    required: true,
    date: true,
    ifDateInCurrentYear : true;
});
});
```